# file does not load properly according to visitor location

Tags: javascript, php

I just need to ask small favor, can you please take a look at this code and what's the problem because it only loads the *ph.php* file even the user is from US that suppose to be *us.php* :

```
<script language='Javascript'> 
var country = geoplugin_countryCode();

switch (country)
{
 case (country = "UK"):
 <?php include( "../../uk.php"); ?>
break;

 case (country = "US"):
 <?php include( "../../us.php"); ?>
break;

 case (country = "PH"):
 <?php include( "../../ph.php"); ?>
break;

} 
</script>
```

## 1 Javascript - Load respective file on respective countries

This is actually an include file called offer.php inside index.php that dynamically call other files depends on what country is the user. For example if somone is from UK then offer-uk.php must load and replace the variables in index.php

## 2) PHP -

I need to load this page normally with this URL format : `www.mydomain.com/index.php?noclid=abc123`
It need to dynamically pass through the `noclid` variable using `$_REQUEST` or whatever just to make it work as `www.mydomain.com/index.php?noclid=abc123`. Inside the *index.php* file, I do `$_GET['clid'] = '[[clid]]';` but the thing is i want to have `noclid=abc123` not `clid=abc123`.

Comment: geo-location is actually working, the only problem is the file does not load properly according to visitor location

Comment: you cant mix server side and client side like that

Comment: So how can i do that

Comment: the problem is it load only the last file, us.php should load instead of ph.php since the visitor is from US

Comment: so i'm thinking if switch is actually the correct one? i tried also if else but work the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many have pointed out, you've probably mixed up how server and client side resources are fetched. You need to understand that, all the code in the `php` side of things is compiled and evaluated into valid `html` when you submit a request for that resource.

Once the page renders in your browser, javascript comes into action. If you still want to `include` specific `php` files as per country code, you would have to make appropriate requests to the server.

So in your case since you are fetching the country code in javascript, you might want to make a request to another php script (let's call it `foo.php`) using a `POST` or `GET` request. You can then include the appropriate files for separate countries in a very similar `switch` statement. Only this `switch` statement would lie in `foo.php`. So `foo.php` could look something like this:

```
 <?php
   $country= $_POST['countryid']; //Assuming you are making a post request and passing 'countryid'

  switch ($country) {
   case "UK":
    include( "../../uk.php");
    break;
   case "US":
    include( "../../us.php");
    break;
  case "PH":
    include( "../../ph.php");
   break;
  default:
   //if you want to handle this case..
  } 
?>
```

The ajax request could simply be:

```
  var country = geoplugin_countryCode();

  ...


  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "foo.php",
  data: { countryid: country}
 })
 .done(function( msg ) {
   //Ajax request completed
 });
```

If you are unclear on how to make a post or get request and pass data along with it, I suggest reading up some documentation on [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Anyway, this is just one of the many ways you can get around your problem. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: the only function i need is to load specific php file acording to visitor location

Comment: How do i convert this into ajax?

Comment: @Narayana, I have added some ajax code snippet that might give you some clarity on what I was suggesting. This assumes that you will use Jquery. However you can make http requests in pure javascript as well. Check this link - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: @Narayana, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped so that others in a similar situation might also benefit out of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Dagon said. You try to mix client side and server side code.

#### server side

if offer.php is included in your index php it will be parsed and **all** includes will executed. I guess they all set the same variables so you only see the effect of the last one. Change the order of your includes and you will see it's always the last one.

#### client side

If you have a look at your generated html and javascript you will probably see something like this:

```
<script language='Javascript'> 
  var country = geoplugin_countryCode();

  switch (country)
  {
    case (country = "UK"):
    break;
  }
  ...
```

This is because your php is done and has generated the html output. You can build javascript code on the server side and send it to the browser to be executed there, but don't expect the browser to execute any php commands.

#### solution

Depends on your problem.
But if you need the country information on the server side you have to pass it to the php script. e.g. call your index.php with index.php?country=US

Comment: please don't be confuse. the geo-redirection code is not related on passing through any variables

Comment: only function i need is to load specific php file acording to visitor location